# Does DseGraphFrame in Java support exporting graphs?

Tags: apache-spark, datastax-enterprise-graph, graphframes, dse-graph-frames

Per [DSE docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/graphAnalytics/dseGraphFrameExport.html), vertices and edges can be exported calling `g.V().hasLabel("Person").write.json("/tmp/person_v_json")` in `dse spark`.

Can the same be achieved using `DseGraphFrame` for the Java SDK? I want to make sure because I can't finda `write()` method.

Comment: Given scala / java interop, you should be able to use the same method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Scala, the result returned by `g.V.hasLabel` (`DseGraphTraversal`) could be explicitly converted into `DataFrame` to which the `write` function is applied.

To achieve the same for Java, you can try to explicitly call `.df` on result, and then use `.write` on it.